# using python to acquire picture

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chrNB.png)

```
def read_random_image():
    folder = r"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test"
    file_path = folder + random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
    pil_im = Image.open(file_path,"r")
    return pil_im
```

I get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/testclassB'
```

I use python to acquire the file, i put my file on the desktop, but everytime i run the code, i got mistaken notice. it cant read class A and class B, i do have class A and class B inside of file, is there anything i can do to let code get the file.

i tried changed its path , and tranfer from D to Desktop, i tried add code i got from internet, but nothing is working

Comment: when i code this    folder = r"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test".  mistaken note will be this :directory:'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/testclassB'    but please pay attention to the end, my code ends with test, but mistaken message ends with testclassB.    when i code  folder = r"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test/classA" .mistaken message will be No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test/classA342.jpg'. after i deleted this A342  there is another pictures cant be detected. I tried put only one picture under this file, even this only one picture still cant be read

Comment: Please do **not** use the comments space for adding info; edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the path in the error message carefully:

```
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/testclassB
```

This isn't looking for a folder called classB under test; it's looking for a folder called testclassB under Desktop.

Either add a slash, or preferably use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to take care of this for you.